# Negative t-value in two-fold interaction from lme-Model

Tags: r, default-value, interaction

I'm working with lme models (R package nlme) and got a significant interaction between two variables (Bloom density: proportion of grassland in landscape). The t-value of this interaction is negative, though, and I couldn't find the meaning of the algebraic sign (+ / -) of t-value in interactions.

Could somebody please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, the codes and the output in question. This will help us have a better grasp of your question.

Comment: Look up how the t-value is defined. Typically it's negative if the parameter estimate is negative.